# grails "unable to resolve class groovy.util.FileNameFinder"

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to modify a grails service that someone else (who is away on leave) set up, but I get this when I try to run grails war or grails run-app:

```
    ...unable to resolve class FileNameFinder 
     @ line 27, column 30.
    def labelFiles = new FileNameFinder().getFileNames(gazetteersFolder, "**/label.txt")
```

I get the same error on a different line if I add "import groovy.util.FileNameFinder" to the top of that class.

How is this possible?  I thought groovy automatically provided (and imported) all of groovy.util.*?

Comment: which grails version you are using?

Comment: @RahulMahadik
$ grails -version
| Grails Version: 3.2.8
| Groovy Version: 2.4.10
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_171

Comment: Have u checked with my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you configured Groovy SDK properly?

You can achieve same with following code:

```
def labelFiles = new FileNameByRegexFinder().getFileNames(gazetteersFolder, "label.txt")
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: That change does work! I'm surprised, because both classes are in the  groovy.util package. Thanks. (My colleague who is much more familiar with grails will be back soon and may be able to tell me why.)